# MYSQL data to long for non-existent column

Tags: mysql

I keep getting this error for an insert into ... update query, the problem, this column 'str' does not exist in the table being updated, or any of the tables I'm pulling data from, and it's not in the query.

```
Error Code: 1406. Data too long for column 'str' at row 215710
```

I'm totally stumped here. It this a mysql bug? I went as far as to isolate the query to just one column, still got this error.

**UPDATE 1:**

I just tried updating with a manual value, on one column only set to longtext. I'm still getting the exact same error.

**UPDATE 2:**

Major update, I isolated the problem down to the select query, the original error implied a table column, however, it seems to be pointing to  what I assume is some kind of temp table column for the following row. When I yanked this out of the query, it worked. Ironically, this is the same column I did my one column test with where I manually entered an value in the update on duplicate key part of my query.

```
CONCAT_WS('', UC_Words(`name`), ' | ', UC_Words(`city`), ' ', UC_Words(`state`), ' ', UC_Words(`country`), CONCAT('|---|',`name-key`)) AS `owner-data`
```

I'm currently using lots of GROUP_CONCAT's, but I have already adjusted the length. Is there a parameter for CONCAT_WS length? NOTE: UC_Words is a custom function. This could possibly be a culprit, still need to test it...

**UPDATE 3:**

The error appears to be a result of the UC_Words function. The 'str' is the name field in that function. Type was set to VARCHAR 255, which was too short.

Comment: Do you know which record is causing that error?  If taken verbatim, it might imply you are trying to insert data too wide.  If a false flag for something else, maybe you are trying to insert the wrong type of data.

Comment: No, the real head scratcher is that the column 'str' does not exist. I have no idea where that is coming from. I've had data too long errors before, but those columns actually existed.

Comment: Can you pare down the situation to a smaller, reproducible, sample which others might then be able to look at?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can, it's a proprietary big data project :( Gonna see if I can isolate the issue row. I did just run the query successfully with a LIMIT 100 thrown in.

Comment: Well you should try, as you can see below your current question is leaving everyone guessing at what the problem is.  Most likely, we don't know more about it than you do.

Comment: See update, I finally isolated to a chunk of code I can share. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

MySQL will truncate any insert value that exceeds the specified column width.

to make this without error try Switch your MySQL mode to not use STRICT.

EDIT:

To change the mode

This can be done in two ways:

Open your "my.ini" file within the MySQL installation directory, and look for the text "sql-mode".
Find:

Code:

## Set the SQL mode to strict

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
Replace with:

Code:

## Set the SQL mode to strict

sql-mode="NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
Or

You can run an SQL query within your database management tool, such as phpMyAdmin:
Code:

SET @@global.sql_mode= '';

Comment: This is not the issue. I just manually entered a tiny value to use for updating, still got the error, on the same row, the column is set to longtext.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be a result of the UC_Words function. The 'str' is the name field in that function. Type was set to VARCHAR 255, which was too short.